# GCP Cloud Run Socket.IO Timeout

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-platform, socket.io, google-cloud-run, google-cloud-build

I'm currently deploying my Socket.IO server with Node.js/Express on Google Cloud Platform using Cloud Build + Run, and it works pretty well.

The issue I'm having is that GCP automatically times out all Socket.IO connections after 1 hour, and it's really annoying. The application I'm running forces it to be run in the background for hours on end, with multiple people in each socket room and interacting with it a bit every 30 mins to 1 hour.

That's why I have 2 questions:

1. How can I gracefully handle these timeouts? I have a reconnection process setup on my client, checking if the socket is connected every 5 seconds, but for some reason it can't detect when these timeouts happen and I'm not sure why.
2. Is there a better platform I can deploy my Socket.IO server on? I don't like the timeouts that GCP sets - would a platform like Digital Ocean or Azure be better?

Comment: Suggestion: design your code to handle connection failures. The Internet is not highly reliable and ISPs, routers, etc can and do drop connections.

Answer (score -1):

[Cloud Run has a max timeout of 3600s](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/configuring/request-timeout) to handle the requests, whatever the protocol (HTTP, HTTP/2, streaming or not). If you need to maintain longer the connexion, Cloud Run isn't the correct platform for this.

I could recommend you to have a look to [App Engine Flex](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible) or to [Autopilot](https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/containers-kubernetes/introducing-gke-autopilot). On both, you have longer timeout and the capacity to run jobs in background. And both accept containers.